# Lower case an entire string in Racket

Tags: string, scheme, racket, lowercase

Is there a way to turn all of the characters in a string into lower case in [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/)?

The only way I can think of is turning char-downcase but it won't work with strings

I am using the beginner language so I can't use some functions

Comment: Thanks Alastair Pitts!

Comment: From the [documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=string#%28tech._string%29):


    `A string is a fixed-length array of characters.`


So your real problem is how to work with arrays.

Answer (score 12):

In practice, you'd use the [`string-downcase`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._string-downcase%29%29) procedure for this:

```
(string-downcase "ABCDE")
=> "abcde"
```

But you're working with the beginner's language, so here's the general idea for solving it - I'll give you some hints, it's better if you try to solve the problem by yourself. First, let's split the problem in two parts: one procedure that converts the string into a list of characters, calls a helper procedure that performs the actual transformation and  finally turns the converted list back into a string:

```
(define (lowercase str)
  (<???>           ; convert the list of chars into a string
   (convert        ; call the helper procedure
    (<???> str)))) ; convert the string into a list of chars
```

The `convert` procedure is a helper, which does the heavy lifting and converts to lowercase each character in a list of characters:

```
(define (convert strlst)
  (if <???>                  ; if the list of chars is empty
      <???>                  ; return the empty list
      (cons                  ; else `cons`
       (<???> <???>)         ; convert to lowercase the first char in list
       (convert <???>))))    ; advance recursion over list
```

The key parts of the solution are the procedures for manipulating [strings](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html) and [characters](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/characters.html), click on the links and study the documentation.